# Variance of means of different populations

Tags: statistics, variance, hypothesis-testing, means

I have 30 different populations with different number of samples for each population and 30 different population means.

If I calculate the variance of those 30 means - does this have a mathematical meaning / specific statistical term (i.e. un-pooled variance)?

Comment: Are you planning to weight the means?

Comment: No, not weighing the means.